# C# javascript enable/disable checkboxes

Tags: c#, checkbox, code-behind

I have some checkboxes dynamically created in C# codebehind. Let's say two columns. This works fine.

I want the checkboxes in the left column to enable/disable those in the right upon check.  I do this by attaching attributes to the checkboxes in codebehind that run javascript to do the enabling/disabling. This works great.

Here's the javascript:

```
function SetPrimaryStatus(target, senders) {
    var dis = "disable";
    var arr = senders.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(arr[i]).checked == true) {
            dis = "";
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(target).disabled = dis;
    if (dis == "disable") document.getElementById(target).checked = false;
}
```

I thought I was home free...I just have to disable the right column checkboxes upon creation in the codebehind (`CheckBox.Enabled = false;`).  Ok.

For whatever reason now, when I check the left checkboxes, the right ones do nothing.  I've set alerts in the javascript and they always come up...and things appear to be set like they should. When I remove the `CheckBox.Enabled = false;` in codebehind, it works again.

In fact, I can start some of the left checkboxes with a check and the corresponding right checkbox I leave enabled. When I run the set(s) that starts enabled works perfect but the set(s) that start with the right checkbox disabled do not.

Is there something other than Enabled that I should be setting in codebehind to start the checkboxes in a disabled state that the javascript can then change?  Is it a matter of true/false compared to "disable"?  I've tried both.

Comment: Do you do postbacks on your page? Do you have update panels? Did it stopped working at all or it works when you first load the page and then it does not any more?

Comment: No postbacks occur during this process of checking/unchecking the checkboxes. So, no update panels are playing a role.  It works great if I leave the dynamic checkboxes enabled in the codebehind and only stops working when I set some of the checkboxes to enabled=false on load.  everything still goes through the javascript.  There's no postback, so no first load, second load thing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/982967.aspx/1.

I had to add `document.getElementById(target).parentElement.disabled = dis;` to my javascript function.  All works as expected now.  Thanks for everyone's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try adding "disabled" attribute. i.e.

```
CheckBox.Attributes["disabled"] = "disable";
```

anyway I think is is better to use `.removeAttribute("diabled")` method instead of setting it's value to empty string.

Comment: I've tried both ways (setting CheckBox.Enabled = false and CheckBox.Attributes["disabled"] = "disable").  Same result.